# Estimate $|f'(0)|$ for an analytic function $f(z)=\sum_{0}^{\infty} a_{k} z^{k}$ on the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}=\mathbb{D}(0,1),$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Suppose that $f(z)=\sum_{0}^{\infty} a_{k} z^{k}$ is analytic on the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}=\mathbb{D}(0,1),$ and that
$f(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}(0,2) .($ Do not assume $f(0)=0 .)$

(a) Prove that $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\left|a_{k}\right|^{2} \leq 4 .$

(b) Using (a), show that $\left|f^{\prime}(0)\right| \leq 2,$ with equality iff $f(z)=c z,$ where $|c|=2$.

Here, Integrating $|f(z)|^{2}$ over a circle of $|z|=r,$ where $r \in(0,1)$ will leads to
$\int_{|z|=r}|f(z)|^2dz=\int_{|z|=r}\sum_{0}^{\infty} a_{k} z^{k}\sum_{0}^{\infty} \bar{a_{k}} \bar{z}^{k}dz$, Now can I proceed by interchanging the summation and integral? or should I use Cauchy integral formula for derivatives at $0$?

Comment: Yes, you can interchange the integral and the sums. Note that $\int z^{k}\overline {z}^{j}=0$ unless $j=k$. Part b) follows from the fact that $|a_1|^{2} \leq \sum |a_k|^{2}$.

Comment: You can interchange sums and integrals if the sums converge uniformly on the contour over which you integrate. Luckily, power series do converge uniformly on compact sets, and your contour is compact.